# Replicar conteúdo de val() em span

Tags: jquery, input

Achei este código que funciona muito bem em inputs:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $("[name='email']").keyup(function() {
        var email = $(this).val();
        $("[name='login']").val(email); }); });

</script>
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder='email' />
<input type="text" name="login" placeholder='login' />
```

Porém fiz algumas modificações querendo fazer funcionar em outros elementos como por exemplo o span.

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $("[name='email']").keyup(function() {
        var email = $(this).val();
        $(email).insertAfter("span.login"); }); });

</script>
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder='email' />
<span class="login"></span>
```

porém não funciona, mas se eu colocar qualquer texto pronto no lugar do $(email).insertAfter ai funciona, existe uma forma de funcionar como funciona no input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para inserir o texto no  pelo id="" você utiliza o .text().
segue o código.

```js
$(function() {
    $("[name='email']").keyup(function() {
        var email = $(this).val();
        $("span.login").text(email);;
    }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="email" placeholder='email' />
<span class="login"></span>
```

Comment: o seu funcionou tão bem quanto o de cima, mas ai vi que você utilizou o text que funciona perfeitamente, o do de cima está com html, vi que em performance o html é melhor, mas, você tem menos medalhas que o de cima, então vou escolher a sua como resposta, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

O normal seria adicionar o seletor do span e utilizar o metodo html() para inserir o texto desta forma:

```js
$("[name='email']").keyup(function() {
  var email = $(this).val();
  $("[name='login']").val(email);
  $("#spanLogin").html(email);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder='email' />
<input type="text" name="login" placeholder='login' />
<span id="spanLogin"></span><span>
```

Comment: funcionou muito bem, e na diferença entre o seu em .html e do amigo abaixo .text, o seu tem mais performance, mas como nosso amigo está com menos medalhas, dei o voto para ele, muito obrigado.